# Learning Resources: Mathematica Notebooks

Tags: self-learning, mathematica

A while ago, I stumbled upon someone's list of Mathematica notebooks for learning various topics.  I've since lost the link, but I'm wondering now if I could find notebooks again.

So my question is:  **Where can we find Mathematica notebooks for learning various topics?**

I'm looking for big notebooks that cover the amount of material that a textbook on the subject would cover.  Other than that, I'm sorry I can't get more specific.

Comment: Amazon? Though even there, much can be out of date. Presumably, the availability of such notebooks / content would depend on the subject matter. /////// As an aside .... a very nice summary of issues for new users is given here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users

Answer (score 1):

A place where one can find Mathematica notebooks to learn about various topics is the Wolfram Documentation Center. It is found inside the Mathematica software (Help section) and online:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/

Another place is the MathWorld website. There are downloadable Mathematica notebooks attached to a good number of mathematical topics. At the top of the topic page just click on the words "Download Mathematica notebook" (if they exist):

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/

There is also a link to a free pdf tutorial entitled "Wolfram Mathematica® Tutorial Collection NOTEBOOKS AND DOCUMENTS":

http://www.johnboccio.com/MathematicaTutorials/13_NotebooksAndDocuments.pdf

The tutorial above is useful even if it refers to an older version of Mathematica.

See also this related question:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice